# Заменить слово в файле

Tags: python

Нужно открыть файл, найти и заменить в нем одно слово (оно встречается в файле 1 раз) и сохранить под другим названием.

На баше эта задача решается вот так:

```
cat /tmp/test/file | sed "s/TEST_OLD/TEST_OLD/"> /tmp/test/file_new
```

C Питоном не очень, представляю что проблема решается как-то примерно так:

```
import re
output_file = open("/tmp/test/file").readlines()
string = "TEST_OLD"
string.replace(string,"TEST_NEW")
open("/tmp/test/file_new", "w")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ну в целом верно, только модуль `re` не нужен, также стоит либо использовать `with`, либо закрывать файлы `file.close()` после использования. Как то так в конечном итоге:

```
with open('test1') as file_in:
    text = file_in.read()

text = text.replace("TEST_OLD", "TEST_NEW")

with open("test2", "w") as file_out:
    file_out.write(text)
```

Да и `readlines()` возвращает список строк и это не совсем то что нам здесь нужно.

**Update 0:**

---

Для замены лучше использовать регулярные выражения, чтобы избежать проблем при включении слова в другие и т.д. Спасибо *@ReinRaus* за замечание.

Обрати внимание на ответ *@andy.37* Если файл объемный, то `read()` плохая идея, поскольку так мы загрузим все содержимое файла в память. Правильный выбор в этом случае - построчное чтение/запись.

Comment: `re` лучше применить. Например нужно заменить слово `скоро`, но внутри может быть куча всего: `скоропостижно`, `скорость`, и прочее

Comment: @ReinRaus да, согласен, лучше замену на регулярных выражениях реализовать, если могут быть подобные проблемы.

Answer (score 2):

Не имеет смысл читать файл целиком и забивать память. Ну и вопрос при замене word -> WORD, менять ли что-то в слове 'sword'?

```
def replace_in_file(file1, file2, pattern, subst, wordonly=True):
   with open(file1, 'r') as f1:
      with open(file2, 'w') as f2:
         for line in f1:
             if wordonly: # заменяем word -> WORD, но не sword -> sWORD
                f2.write(re.sub('\b{}\b'.format(pattern), subst, line)
             else: # заменяем и word -> WORD и sword -> sWORD
                f2.write(line.replace(pattern, subst))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
oldfile = open("file", "r")
newfile = open("file_new", "w")
for line in oldfile:
    s = line.replace("TEST_OLD","TEST_NEW")
    newfile.write(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы выполнить аналог: `sed 's/OLD/NEW/' file >file_new`:

```
from pathlib import Path

Path('file_new').write_text(Path('file').read_text().replace('OLD', 'NEW'))
```

Чтобы не заменять все подстроки, а только целые слова, можно регулярные выражения использовать: [Замена в файле списка слов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/801324/23044).

Чтобы не загружать весь файл целиком в память, можно построчно замену производить.  См. [Как заменить строчку в .txt файле через python 3?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/654183/23044)

---

В случае, если замена имеет ту же длину в байтах и результат вы хотите в тот же файл записать (по месту замена), можно `mmap` воспользоваться:

```
from mmap import ACCESS_WRITE, mmap

old, new = b'OLD', b'NEW'
with open('file', 'r+b') as file, mmap(file.fileno(), 0, access=ACCESS_WRITE) as s:
    i = s.find(old)
    if i != -1:
        s[i:i+len(old)] = new
```

В этом случае файл не переписывается целиком, а только нужное место обновляется.