# Как сделать замену строк на Python

Tags: python

1. Есть файл --- в котором нужно заменить строки: userbouquet.obshie.tv
2. Есть файл --- откуда берём строки на замену: _Триколор.txt
   Эти замены нормально проходят в Notepad++ --- только это очень долго и неудобно.

Нужен простой скрипт на Python, который будет из файла ( _Триколор.txt) будет построчно брать данные и производить замену в файле (userbouquet.obshie.tv)

1. userbouquet.obshie.tv

   ```
   #NAME Общие
   #SERVICE 4097:0:1:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:http%3a//ott-cdn.ucom.am/s92/index.m3u8:Зоо ТВ
   #DESCRIPTION Зоо ТВ
   #SERVICE 4097:0:1:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:http%3a//31.184.192.35%3a12008:Драйв
   #DESCRIPTION Драйв
   #SERVICE 4097:0:1:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:http%3a//live-nikatv.cdnvideo.ru/nikatv/nikatv.sdp/playlist.m3u8:Ника TV (Калуга)
   #DESCRIPTION Ника TV (Калуга)
   #SERVICE 4097:0:1:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:http%3a//ott-cdn.ucom.am/s20/index.m3u8:ЦТВ
   #DESCRIPTION ЦТВ
   #SERVICE 4097:0:1:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:http%3a//serv24.vintera.tv%3a8081/svoetv/stvsd/playlist.m3u8:Свое ТВ (Ставрополь)
   #DESCRIPTION Свое ТВ (Ставрополь)
   #SERVICE 4097:0:1:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:http%3a//stream.tvbelgorod.ru%3a8080/mirbelogorya/index.m3u8:Мир Белогорья
   #DESCRIPTION Мир Белогорья
   ```
2. Есть файл --- откуда берём строки на замену: _Триколор.txt

   ```
   В Notepad++ включаем: Заменить. и Регулярные выражения. !!!
   ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
   ==================================
   Найти:
   (^.*)4097:0:1:0:0:0:0:0:0:0(.*:Ника ТВ\s*$)
   Заменить всё:
   #SERVICE 4097$14097:0:1:4E22:2:FD:1680000:0:0:0$2
   ==================================
   Найти:
   (^.*)4097:0:1:0:0:0:0:0:0:0(.*:Своё ТВ\s*$)
   Заменить всё:
   #SERVICE 4097$14097:0:1:6154:7:FD:1680000:0:0:0$2
   ==================================
   Найти:
   (^.*)4097:0:1:0:0:0:0:0:0:0(.*:Мир Белогорья\s*$)
   Заменить всё:
   #SERVICE 4097$14097:0:1:4E31:2:FD:1680000:0:0:0$2
   =================================
   Найти:
   (^.*)4097:0:1:0:0:0:0:0:0:0(.*:Центральное Телевидение\s*$)
   Заменить всё:
   #SERVICE 4097$14097:0:1:3E9:1:FD:1680000:0:0:0$2
   =================================
   Найти:
   (^.*)4097:0:1:0:0:0:0:0:0:0(.*:Север\s*$)
   Заменить всё:
   #SERVICE 4097$14097:0:1:7D7:2:FD:1680000:0:0:0$2
   =================================
   ```

   PS  Если строка в файле (userbouquet.obshie.tv)  встречается несколько раз, то заменить нужно во всех строках.
   Файл (_Триколор.txt) можно изменить как угодно.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Заменить слово в файле](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/490305/%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be-%d0%b2-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%b5)

Comment: а на что заменить нужно?

Comment: Есть файл --- откуда берём строки на замену: _Триколор.txt

Comment: Алгоритм. 1) Читаем в память `userbouquet.obshie.tv`. 2) Считываем поблочно `_Триколор.txt`, формируем regex и применяем через **`re.sub`** к файлу `userbouquet.obshie.tv` в памяти. 3) Повторяем 2, пока `_Триколор.txt` не закончен. 4) Сохраняем результат в файл  `userbouquet.obshie.tv`. А уж код - извольте написать сами...